# Application Stopped unexpectedly while getting names of installed packages

Tags: android

I am using following code but when I run it , it "stops unexpectedly"

I have given permissions as bellow

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
```

Whats wrong with this code:

```
import java.util.List;        
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public static  String Tag = "Task";
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Intent service = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
           List<ApplicationInfo> pis = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);        

        for (ApplicationInfo appinfo : pis) 
        {
            String S1=appinfo.className.toString();
            Log.i(Tag,S1);

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the installed applications one by one.

Comment: Please upload the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `appinfo.className` can be `null`. Try this:

```
for (ApplicationInfo appinfo : pis) 
{
    Log.i(Tag, "" + appinfo.className);
}
```

and you will see a lot of null values in your log.